# Uninstalling Webmin, without losing setup?

Tags: security, website, uninstall

I've used webmin to help set up my server, but now I want to uninstall it, as I no longer need it at all and I'd like to remove the possibility of people getting into the admin section with my password - it seems unlikely but it's best to leave as few things open as possible, right?

Anyways, the webmin doc says I can do /etc/webmin/uninstall.sh to uninstall it, easy peasy. But, will I lose my settings for e.g. Apache and Postgres by doing that, considering I set them up within webmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will **not** lose your settings that were configured by Webmin. Webmin simply provides you with a user-friendly frontend that modifies the configuration files for you and restarts the services when necessary. By uninstalling Webmin, you are only removing the frontend and any tools that were included with it, not any of the services/configurations it controls.

Unless Apache and PostgreSQL were installed as a bundle with Webmin, they won't be disappearing from your disk when you perform the uninstall :)

Comment: Awesome! Well, Apache and PostgreSQL were both installed from within webmin, but it said it was using apt-get to install so that should be fine... right?

Comment: @Java yes, it will be fine.